# Change option height not updating when .trigger("chosen:updated") is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am updating the items of my select options by using .trigger("chosen:updated") but the total height is not updating.

When an item is removed, it shows like this:

[image]

When an item is added, it has scrolls:

[image]

I tried this:

```
$select.trigger("chosen:updated");
$select.css('height', '100%');
```

**EDIT:**

I created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tawfh60t/7/

Comment: Hi kindly include your code, and let's see what you've already came up with.

Comment: Items are refresh whenever $select is clicked. So basically, when an item is added or removed i call $select.trigger("chosen:updated"). But the height is not updating.